# Java: count number of objects created - contsructor (call to this)

Tags: java, object, constructor, count, this

**Count No. of Created Object - Constructor**

I want to count the number of objects I created.

```
 class ctt
 {
    static int counter = 0;
    public ctt()
    {
        this(2.3);
        System.out.println("default ctt");
    }

    public ctt(double a)
    {
        System.out.println("Double ctt");
    }

    public ctt(int a)
    {
        this();
        System.out.println("Int ctt");
        counter++; 
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
       ctt c1 = new ctt(4); 
       ctt c2 = new ctt();

       System.out.println("No.of object created: "+counter);
    }
}
```

In which constructor counter++ has to come. [ If I give counter++ in all construtor method, counter++ is incremented to 3 for first object creation itself. ]

```
       ctt c1 = new ctt(4);
```

When I create c1 object, counter++ is incremented to 1.

```
       ctt c2 = new ctt();
```

This c2 object is not getting incremented.
Can any give Solution to this problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to increment the counter in c  (double a ) . This is because it is called in  c  () and also in c  (int a) which in turn call c  () which subsequently calls c  (double a)

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a homework assignment, so I will answer it based on this. If I am wrong, please comment and I will update my answer:

Look at the places that actually increase the counter (there is only one) and then look at how the signature of this method/constructor is different from the others. That should help you understand what is going on.

If that still does not help, use a debugger starting from your calling code and step through your code.

Comment: where should I increment the counter var?

Comment: I was confused before.. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor with integer as argument only has the statement to increment counter.

the statement `ctt c1 = new ctt(4)` this calls `ctt(int a)` and

the statement   `ctt c2 = new ctt();` --> calls `ctt()` which does not increments the counter.

If you need both your constructors to increment, you need to increment the counter in your ctt() constructor too. *i.e the constructor that doesn't take any arguments.*

Comment: If I give counter++ to default constructor, it will affect the c1 object also. c1 -> get incremented two times. c2 -> get incremented one time. Output will get : 3 but should be 2.